# My script produces javascript stuffs Instead of valid links

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

Running my script I get "javascript:getDetail(19978)" such items as href. The number in braces if concatenated with "https://www.aopa.org/airports/4M3/business/", produces valid links. However, clicking on this newly created links I can see that It gets me to a different page which is not similar to the one if clicked from the original page link. How can I get the original links instead of "javascript:getDetail(19978)". Search should be made writing "All" in the searchbox.
The code I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
link = "https://www.aopa.org/airports/4M3/business/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/")

driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm').send_keys('All')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()
time.sleep(5)
for pro in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td/a'):
    print(pro.get_attribute("href"))
driver.quit()
```

Code to create new links with the base url I pasted in my description:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
link = "https://www.aopa.org/airports/4M3/business/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/")
driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm').send_keys('All')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()
time.sleep(5)
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td/a'):
    fresh = item.get_attribute("href").replace("javascript:getDetail(","")
    print(link + fresh.replace(")",""))
driver.quit()
```

However, this newly created links lead me to different destinations.

FYC, original links are embedded within elements like the below one:

```
<td><a href="javascript:getDetail(19978)">GOLD DUST FLYING SERVICE, INC.</a></td>
```

Comment: I'm seriously confused about which answer to accept as both the answers given underneath by two python giants are working like charm.

Comment: Don't scold me or take otherwise if I go wrong. Sir Andersson has given the answer first so I'm gonna accept it. I've upvoted both the answers, though.

Comment: Don't worry about that. The important thing is that the problem is solved. Thanks for a good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking link you make an `XHR`. The page is actually remained the same, but received data from `JSON` rendered instead of previous content.

If you want to open raw data inside an `HTML` page you might try something like

```
# To get list of entries as ["19978", "30360", ... ]
entries = [a.get_attribute('href').split("(")[1].split(")")[0] for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td/a')]
url = "https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/wsSearch.cfm?method=schoolDetail&businessId="
for entry in entries:
    driver.get(url + entry)
    print(driver.page_source)
```

You also might use `requests` to get each `JSON` response as

```
import requests
for entry in entries:
    print(requests.get(url + entry).json())
```

without rendering data in browser

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your speckless solution.

Comment: Sir Andersson, could you please give me a hint where have you discovered this "https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/wsSearch.cfm?method=schoolDetail&businessId=" link from? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press `F12` in your browser-> switch to "Network" ("Net") tab-> switch to "XHR" tab-> click on required link... You'll see that new request sent. Click on new request entry -> check "Headers"->"RequestURL"

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how `getDetail()` is implemented in the source code and explore the "network" tab when you click each of the search result links, you may see that there are multiple XHR requests issued for a result and there is some client-side logic executed to form a search result page.

If you don't want to dive into replicating all the logic happening to form each of the search result pages - simply go back and forth between the search results page and a single search result page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/")
driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm').send_keys('All')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()

# wait for search results to be visible
table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#searchResults table")))

for index in range(len(table.find_elements_by_css_selector('td a[href*=getDetail]'))):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#searchResults table")))

    # get the next link
    link = table.find_elements_by_css_selector('td a[href*=getDetail]')[index]
    link_text = link.text
    link.click()

    print(link_text)
    # TODO: get details

    # go back
    back_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#schoolDetail a[href*=backToList]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", back_link)

driver.quit()
```

Note the use of [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of hardcoded "sleeps".

---

It may actually make sense to avoid using selenium here altogether and approach the problem "headlessly" - doing HTTP requests (via `requests` module) to the website's API.

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your flawless solution.